# Vagrant, how to access/sync phpmyadmin on host machine

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, vagrant

I want to setup a vagrant developing environment (with chef/debian-7.4 from Vagrant Cloud) for PHP & MySQL, but I can't figure out how to share and navigate my 'phpmyadmin' directory from the host web browser, I'm used to localhost:port/phpmyadmin.

So how do I make phpmyadmin accessible from this web address.

Obviously, it's my first time setting up a vagrant development environment, I'm following this guide: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/

Comment: Have you forwarded the host *port* (whatever that is in your URI above) to guest port 80? Have you installed phpMyAdmin in the guest?

Comment: Yes and I can access it. I just found this: http://jeh3.net/phpmyadmin-auto-login-ubuntu-1204-vagrant-vm-puppet , but I dont know how to use this script.

Comment: Please clarify your question. You have setup vagrant with the chef/debian-7.4 base box and installed PHP and MySQL? Did you also install phpmyadmin inside the vagrant box? Did you setup port forwarding?

Comment: Yes, I added the port forwarding line to the Vagrantfile and I installed all of the software INSIDE the vagrant box.

Answer (score 6):

Turned out I wasn't too familiar with phpmyadmin and the `ln` command, I executed `ln -fs /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www` and it now works.